# where did my configuration run off to?

Tags: django, virtualenv

My team upgraded our Django site to 1.7.  I created a NEW virtualenv, pip-installed the requirements, everything looks fine, i have django 1.7 in the new virtualenv.

> > > import django
> > >       django.VERSION
> > >       (1, 7, 4, 'final', 0)

But when I try to run the new branch locally, I get this..

```
(venv1)josh@josh:~/project$ ./manage.py runnserver_plus
/home/josh/.virtualenvs/venv1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dotenv.py:53: UserWarning: Not reading ./.env - it doesn't exist.
  warnings.warn("Not reading {0} - it doesn't exist.".format(dotenv))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    from configurations.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/venv1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/configurations/management.py", line 3, in <module>
    importer.install(check_options=True)
  File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/venv1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/configurations/importer.py", line 35, in install
    importer = ConfigurationImporter(check_options=check_options)
  File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/venv1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/configurations/importer.py", line 54, in __init__
    self.validate()
  File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/venv1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/configurations/importer.py", line 82, in validate
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(self.error_msg.format(self.namevar))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Configuration cannot be imported, environment variable DJANGO_CONFIGURATION is undefined.
```

So just for giggles I did a little...

```
(venv1)josh@josh:~/project$ source dev.env
```

It didn't exactly fix the issue completely but when I run the server now..

```
 (venv1)josh@josh:~/project$ ./manage.py runserver_plus
/home/josh/.virtualenvs/venv1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dotenv.py:53: UserWarning: Not reading ./.env - it doesn't exist.
  warnings.warn("Not reading {0} - it doesn't exist.".format(dotenv))
/home/josh/fizzbuzz/fizzbuzz/fizzbuzz/tagging/managers.py:10: RemovedInDjango18Warning: `ModelTagManager.get_query_set` method should be renamed `get_queryset`.

/home/josh/fizzbuzz/fizzbuzz/fizzbuzz/tagging/forms.py:11: RemovedInDjango18Warning: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is deprecated - form TagAdminForm needs updating

/home/josh/.virtualenvs/venv1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py:143: RemovedInDjango18Warning: `PermissionAdmin.queryset` method should be renamed `get_queryset`.
  .__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs))

/home/josh/fizzbuzz/fizzbuzz/fizzbuzz/common/forms.py:97: RemovedInDjango18Warning: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is deprecated - form AddressForm needs updating
  class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm, FizzbuzzDisplayFormMixin):

/home/josh/fizzbuzz/fizzbuzz/fizzbuzz/clients/admin.py:25: RemovedInDjango18Warning: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is deprecated - form PaymentModelForm needs updating
  class PaymentModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

/home/josh/fizzbuzz/fizzbuzz/fizzbuzz/bookkeeper/admin.py:9: RemovedInDjango18Warning: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is deprecated - form InvoiceForm needs updating
  class InvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):

Validating models...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

Django version 1.7.4, using settings 'fizzbuzz.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the Werkzeug debugger (http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/)
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8000/
 * Restarting with reloader
/home/josh/.virtualenvs/venv1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dotenv.py:53: UserWarning: Not reading ./.env - it doesn't exist.
  warnings.warn("Not reading {0} - it doesn't exist.".format(dotenv))
/home/josh/fizzbuzz/fizzbuzz/fizzbuzz/tagging/managers.py:10: RemovedInDjango18Warning: `ModelTagManager.get_query_set` method should be renamed `get_queryset`.

/home/josh/fizzbuzz/fizzbuzz/fizzbuzz/tagging/forms.py:11: RemovedInDjango18Warning: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is deprecated - form TagAdminForm needs updating

/home/josh/.virtualenvs/venv1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py:143: RemovedInDjango18Warning: `PermissionAdmin.queryset` method should be renamed `get_queryset`.
  .__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs))

/home/josh/fizzbuzz/fizzbuzz/fizzbuzz/common/forms.py:97: RemovedInDjango18Warning: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is deprecated - form AddressForm needs updating
  class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm, FizzbuzzDisplayFormMixin):

/home/josh/fizzbuzz/fizzbuzz/fizzbuzz/clients/admin.py:25: RemovedInDjango18Warning: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is deprecated - form PaymentModelForm needs updating
  class PaymentModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

/home/josh/fizzbuzz/fizzbuzz/fizzbuzz/bookkeeper/admin.py:9: RemovedInDjango18Warning: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is deprecated - form InvoiceForm needs updating
  class InvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):

Validating models...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

Django version 1.7.4, using settings 'fizzbuzz.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the Werkzeug debugger (http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/)
```

..but the server does run and pukes out all these errors.

I have tried to figure out what all this means, tried removing and reinstalling my virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper, I just don't know what's going on here. Are the warning below just django code issues needing to be resolved due to the upgrade, or are they possibly still virtualenv problems?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Silly question, but did you `pip install Django==1.7.4`?

Comment: Can you post your manage.py? i am curious about something :P

Comment: @cdvv7788  ''import os
import sys
import dotenv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "fizzbuzz.settings")

    dotenv.read_dotenv()

    from configurations.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)'

Comment: @erip - I created a new virtual env and pip installed my requirements file, which has Django 1.7.4.  That does the same thing, right?

Comment: I think your issue is in your manage.py...try creating a project with djangoadmin in 1.7. My manage.py does set DJANGO_CONFIGURATION: #!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config")
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_CONFIGURATION", "Local")

    from configurations.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

Comment: Basic project structure may need changes, but that should give you some light